# Snapping issue with rotation turned on

Tags: snapping

I'm having an issue with the snap tool. Everytime I try to snap two objects together, if I'm using the option "align rotation to target", the one I'm trying to snap goes through the other. I've already set the origin to the active face, and have no problems when I only use the option "project individual elements", but most of the times I need to attach an object to a face that is on a weird angle, so I need the object to rotate. I'm positive there has to be an easy fix or something I'm unaware of, but this issue has been driving me insane for days now. Thanks in advance

[image: example]